# Only getting diffs in Atlassians Fisheye tool

Tags: atlassian-fisheye, code-search

Sometimes when searching code using Fisheye from Atlassian, I only get results under the Diffs tab.  Does this mean that the code used to reference what I search but no longer does since it does not show up under content?

Answer (score 0):

That's right -- 'content' searches only HEAD revision.